# What is the difference between webpack --env.production and --mode="production"

Tags: javascript, webpack

Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as I understand from the documentation,

`--env` [option](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) is used **ONLY** for being able to get access to it within `webpack.config.js` if it exports a function e.g.

```
module.exports = function(env, options) {
  console.log(env); // "production"
}
```

and let's say that I have my entry point `index.js` with the following code:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // undefined ???
```

**I wonder if**
`process.env.NODE_ENV` won't be assigned to any value regardless I pass `--env.production` or `--env.development`

**I wonder if**
webpack will enable any sort of optimizations automatically depending on a value for `--env`

---

`--mode` [option](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/) is used to enable some bunch of optimizations right away and it will set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to be accessible inside my source files, e.g.

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // "production" OR "development", etc ???
```

**I wonder if**
`process.env.NODE_ENV` will be assigned to any value accessing it from within `webpack.config.js`

**I wonder if**
Let's say that I run webpack with the following command `$ webpack --mode="development"`

and I have the following contents of `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

so, will the `devtool` option eventually be set to `eval`(if I weren't redefining `devtool` in my `webpack.config.js` or the value will be `source-map`, so it will be rewritten with those from my `webpack.config.js` file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I asked a similar question here: [Webpack environment variables confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59563484/webpack-environment-variables-confusion)

**First of all:** both options have nothing to do with `process.env.NODE_ENV`. Yeah, it's confusing especially because the docs mention `NODE_ENV` many times.

> webpack's environment variables are different from the environment variables of operating system shells like bash and CMD.exe

- `--env` command-line option basically allows you to change the value of `env.{some property}` so if you just pass `--env.production` `env.NODE_ENV` will be `undefined` and `env.production` will be set to `true`. You would need to set it separately with `--env.NODE_ENV=yourvalue`. **Note this has nothing to do with `process.env`**. `env` is just the object passed as parameter to your function exported from `webpack.config.js`.
- `--mode` command-line option was introduced in webpack v4 and you can use it to set `process.env.NODE_ENV` **on [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) only** to one of 3 values - `development`, `production` or `none`. It looks like it was made exclusively for DefinePlugin. If you try to  `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);` inside your webpack config it will be `undefined`. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7074

If you want to read those options you need to export a function instead of an object from your `webpack.config.js`.

```
// webpack --mode=production --env.foo=bar --env.NODE_ENV=production
var config = {
  entry: './app.js'
  //...
};

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // undefined!! unless you really set it in OS or with cross-env

module.exports = (env, argv) => {

  console.log(argv.mode); // will print "production"
  console.log(env.foo); // will print "bar"

  return config;
};
```

### cross-env

People also use `cross-env` to set `process.env.NODE_ENV` and they don't use webpack's --env or --mode at all.

The only reason for using `cross-env` would be if you had multiple configs in your project like `postcss.config.js` and `webpack.config.js` and you wanted to set your environment just once, use `process.env.NODE_ENV` everywhere and be done with it. It just won't work with [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) out of the box.

You could also do this if you don't want to use cross-env:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = argv.mode;
    
  return config;
};
```

or set mode based on process.env.NODE_ENV:

```
var config = {
  entry: './app.js',
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV
  //...
};
```

### update 2021

webpack now added a new option `--node-env` so you don't need to rely on cross-env unless you use it in other places https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2362#issuecomment-771776945