# Webpack environment variables confusion

Tags: webpack, cross-env

**[edit: I think I answered my own question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259238/what-is-the-difference-between-webpack-env-production-and-mode-production)**

I see many projects using `cross-env` with webpack but what for?

I see webpack 4 has `--mode` option which sets `NODE_ENV` for us but you can only choose 3 values (production,development,none so this is pretty much a standard now): https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

In webpack >=3 there is `--env` command-line option which basically allows you to set `process.env.{some property}`

So we have 4 ways now to manage environment variables... Can you explain why is it so confusing?

- `webpack --env.NODE_ENV=local --env.production` (v3 official example... NODE_ENV won't be set to production)
- `webpack --env.NODE_ENV=development`
- `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack`
- `webpack --mode=development`

Related question: [What is the difference between webpack --env.production and --mode="production"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259238/what-is-the-difference-between-webpack-env-production-and-mode-production)

More people are confused: https://www.jonathancreamer.com/webpack-production-environment-is-not-the-node_env-or-babel_env-environment-variable/

If I understand correctly in v4 `--mode` is the *right standard way* to set "development"/"production" so I will stick to that.